# Can you put 'break' in the function and end 'while'?

Tags: while-loop

I am a high school student living in Korea.
I came here because I had a problem while making a simple quiz program.
If the s value goes down below 0, I want to end the program.
So I wrote the code as shown in the photo, but the message "'break' outside loop" keeps popping up.
Should I use something other than 'break' to solve this problem?
I want to know what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you added some of the actualy related code instead of an image, and add the related tags, looks like python if im not mistaken #hta

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In particular [please do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).